# missing config_backend in civicrm_domain table, templates_c directory and Config.IDS.ini after migration

Tags: database, missing

I didn't do the database dumps or file backups for this migration of CiviCRM on wordpress, so could it be a problem I can solve without going back to the old host?

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem the site is having?

In later versions there is no config_backend field, and templates_c and config.ids.ini will recreate themselves if the folder permissions are correct.

Comment: I am trying to transfer a replica of a site from one host to another. The old host sent me the public_html files and the wp and civi databases. I did a fresh install of wp (without wp_content) and a fresh install of ciivi, but it wouldn't link to the database on install. I tried to create a blank database with the same name, which allowed install, but couldn't then import the real database without critical error, 505, etc. Are there tables I must remove for a successful import? My server is running PHP 7.3. All folder permissions are correct and I have all privileges on the databases.

Comment: Are these the instructions you're following? https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/

Comment: no. it was recommended to do a fresh Civi install, not a direct file transfer. should i start again? will that skip the wp plugin activation process?

Comment: starting from scratch following the link did the trick. thanks.